# echo to page while PHP loads

Tags: php, echo

I'm putting together a search engine in php that loops over some directories and echos filtered results as it goes.

My issue is that the echoing, isn't executed until all the searching is finished, causing the page to remain blank until the script is complete.

Is this normal? And if so, how can I get the search results to display at the time the echo is called?

I'll also be eventually writing images in the results to the screen. Instead of echoing everything, could calling a JS document.write function instead speed things up by utilizing both client and server sides simultaneously?

**edit:** Here's the code that is iterating. I have a tagging system, but that part is commented out at the moment...

```
function checkTags($dir, $search){
  global $tag;
  $filesInDir = array_map('strtolower', scandir($dir)); // lower case the files
  $filterOut = array('.','..');
  $filesInDir = array_diff($filesInDir, $filterOut); // get rid of the current '.' and parent '..' values
             //   print_r($filesInDir);


  foreach($filesInDir as $file) {
    if($file == $tag) {  // found a tag
      echo 'found tag: '.$file.'<br>';
   /*   $tagDir = dirname($tag);
      $tagContents = strtolower(file_get_contents($file).'<br>'.$tagDir); // adding full path to include parent dirs in tag searching

      foreach($search as $s){
        if(strpos($tagContents, $s) !== false){ // the tag has a search word
          //getFiles($tagDir);
        }
      }  */
    }
    elseif(is_dir($dir.'/'.$file) !== false) { //is a folder, so try in there
      //print_r($file);
      echo 'found dir: '.htmlspecialchars($file).'<br>';
      checkTags($dir.'\\'.$file, $search);
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Well you haven't shown your code at all such that advice might be given on how to modify the code to echo results as the search is in progress.

Comment: @MikeBrant code added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to flush output to the client, use PHP's [flush()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) function.

That said, if you're doing complex processing on page load, that's a bad user experience.  It's more complex, but you'll provide a much better product if you serve up *something* to the user, even if it's just an empty but complete template, then pull in the expensive data asynchronously with AJAX, as happyaccidents suggested.

Comment: This is the correct answer in to achieve what the OP asked with PHP but probably not recommended as it wouldn't be a very nice UX

Comment: @dimo414 I tried putting flush() after the echo call but had no luck. I'll have to research AJAX, still looking for an example of how to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not document.write but certainly look into JavaScript and Ajax techniques to achieve your goal.

Checkout http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming) for an overview of Ajax.

If you're a beginner with JavaScript it might be worth looking at the jQuery library. In particular the .ajax method.

http://jquery.com/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to quote some things from @dimo414's reference

> Several servers, especially on Win32, will still buffer the output from your script until it terminates before transmitting the results to the browser.
>
> Server modules for Apache like mod_gzip may do buffering of their own that will cause flush() to not result in data being sent immediately to the client.
>
> Even the browser may buffer its input before displaying it. Netscape, for example, buffers text until it receives an end-of-line or the beginning of a tag, and it won't render tables until the  tag of the outermost table is seen.
>
> Some versions of Microsoft Internet Explorer will only start to display the page after they have received 256 bytes of output, so you may need to send extra whitespace before flushing to get those browsers to display the page.

which basically means there's no guarantee that flush() will actually send intermediate data to the client, or that the client will display them.

If you want to test if flush() works then disable any apache modules that may be causing buffering on the server. Even then the browser will probably wait untill the page has done loading, or has loaded a certain number of bytes, so the most reliable way to test it is with netcat.

In my experience the only reason a client will see output before the end of script is because I messed up and put an infinite loop with an echo somewhere. In that case the browser will freeze untill apache decides to kill the script. As others have said [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) is the way to go for this one.